# How do I get rid of the GCP Cloud Build Timeout Error

Tags: google-cloud-build

Hi I am submitting a config for cloud build but it keeps timing out.

```
 gcloud builds submit --config cloudbuild.yaml . --timeout=500s
```

The timeout message is as follows

```
Your build timed out. Use the [--timeout=DURATION] flag to change the timeout threshold.
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) build 283b72fa-cef1-425d-b21e-7bf653d22e4b completed with status "TIMEOUT"
```

Comment: Try the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58299693/where-is-set-global-limit-for-gcloud-steps-timeout-for-all-builds

Answer (score 3):

You could try a couple of things:

- Increasing the timeout duration of the flag if you haven't already.
- Instead of using the `--timeout` flag, add the `timeout` field inside the `cloudbuild.yaml`. You can either do that for [each step](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#timeout) or for the [whole build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#timeout_2). [Here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/create-basic-configuration#creating_a_build_config) you can find more information about how to create a configuration file.