# Where is set global limit for gcloud steps timeout for all builds?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

Where can I find global limit for gcloud build step timeout?

This is my gcloud build config:

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/yarn'
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/yarn'
    args: ['build-nginx-config']
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/yarn'
    args: ['build']
    timeout: 3601s
  ...
timeout: 7200s
```

And this is what I get when I try to run this build:

```
[10:41:45]ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) INVALID_ARGUMENT: invalid build:
invalid timeout in build step #2:
build step timeout "1h0m1s" must be <= build timeout "1h0m0s"
```

So somewhere we have setup max for step timeout and I cannot find this place.
Any advice?

**UPD** so it looks like build step timeout cannot be more than 1h.
But you can skip it completely and in this case step timeout is unlimited. The only limit remaining - is the overall build timeout limit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the global timeout for your whole build execution by adding the `timeout` element at the root level of your `cloudbuild.yaml` file, like so:

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/yarn'
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/yarn'
    args: ['build-nginx-config']
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/yarn'
    args: ['build']
    timeout: 3601s
  ...
timeout: 3602s // This value is > to your build step's timeout
```

The default value for the whole build timeout is 10min, as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#timeout_2). You can override this value by setting it explicitly in your file and set a value to up to 24h.

If you submit your build via the `gcloud` tool (which I see you do), the default timeout is set to 10min by default also [there](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set#timeout). You can override it by running:

```
gcloud config set builds/timeout 7200
```

Comment: Yes I know about this option. But what I need is to set `timeout: 3601s` for the step.  And I cannot - I am getting the error described.

Comment: What @LundinCast says is correct. How can you have a step that can last more than the entire build? That's what the error message tells you as well.

Comment: @siamsot No he is not. I have this global timeout set to `timeout: 7200s`

Comment: I've updated my answer with how to update the default gcloud build tiemout as requested.

Comment: @LundinCast you are talking about overall build time. and I am talking about build step time. Apparently build step is limited to 1h and I want to know if this can be customised. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: There isn't any default timeout value set for individual build steps, as documented here; https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/api/reference/rest/Shared.Types/Build#BuildStep

Comment: I confirm I'm able to submit a build with step timeout > 3600s so it's not a hard limit. It seems you have a global build timeout set somewhere.

Comment: So what I see from that doc - build step timeout is limited to overall build timeout.
So all I need to do is to remove custom step timeout and increase build timeout.
@LundinCast thank you again!

Comment: is it possible to set timeout dynamically? (using env var or substitutions)